# Populating Web Page Content From Database

Tags: php, populate

Question: When populating a webpage with content from database should you
1) query the database & display the content retrieved?
or
2) query the database & save the retrieved content to a variable & use the variable to populate the database so as to not make constant unnecessary queries to the database each time the user refreshes the page? Then update the variable only when the database changes.

Comment: Is the content coming from the database static or will it change for every page? Cache the pages if possible.

Comment: Generally speaking, for most non-commercial apps, it's safe to start with displaying the content immediately. Later you can come back and analyze performance bottlenecks and implement caching layers.

Comment: @Blender, the content only changes if the user does a inventory update. The main display on all pages is the same query, just sorted and displayed by different columns on each page.

Comment: @JasonLocke: Cache all non-critical pages for a short amount of time.

Comment: caching is the best solution. you can clear your cache on any update,insert or delete!